# How to render QDialog to QImage with title bar?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to render a QDialog to a QImage, the code is very simple:

```
    QImage img(_dialog->size(), QImage::Format_RGBA8888);

    {
        QPainter painter(&img);
        _dialog->render(&painter);
    }

    img.save("xxx.png");
```

My dialog has a title bar, but I can't see it in the saved image, what should I do to render the title bar?

I also tried `grab()`, titile bar is missing too:

```
_dialog->grab().save("xxx.png");
```

Comment: Is the dialog actually visible on screen? Or is it just in memory?

Comment: It's visible on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dialog is actaully visible on screen, then you can use `QScreen::grabWindow()`, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscreen.html#grabWindow In this function you can specify the rectangle coordinates you want to grab, so use the rectangle which you obtain from `QWidget::frameGeometry()` which includes the window title bar and frame. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#frameGeometry-prop

If the dialog is not visible on screen then I think you are out of luck, Qt probably cannot help you.

Comment: That's an option. It might grab pixels of other windows. I will accept your answer if no one has better idea.